# Adding a delay in a JavaScript Slideshow

Tags: javascript, css

I have been trying to use this slideshow:
[How to create buttons and make it work in a slideshow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44767074/how-to-create-buttons-and-make-it-work-in-a-slideshow/)

but the images transition immediately, I would like a 5 second delay before they move on. How can I edit the code (JS or CSS) to add this delay. Unfortunately JavaScript isn't my forte. Hopefully this will be a simple addition to the code.

Comment: Checkout `setTimeout` built-in.

Comment: Perhaps you should share your code.https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

### Delays in Javascript

Explore the `setTimeout()` function [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp). This is the preferred way to delay code blocks in Javascript.

Try using this function in the

```
_slideTo: function(slide)
```

area of your code.

Comment: Thanks! :) Turns out the function had a timer set in but it was the same length as the fade effect in the CSS. Increasing it has allowed the slides to stay on the screen before changing.

Comment: If this answer solved your question, please rate as best answer.